Prove the following inequality where the constraint is an inequality too
For $a,b,c>0$ and $a^2 +b^2 +c^2 \leqslant a+b+c$ prove the following inequality and show when we have equality :
$F=\dfrac{1}{a^2 +b^2 +c^2 } +\frac{a^3}{b} +\frac{b^3 }{c} +\frac{c^3 }{a} \geqslant 1 $
My approach to the proof :
firstly use the constraint to compare and apply Radon's Inequality : $F\geqslant \frac{1}{a+b+c} + \frac{a^3 }{b} + \frac{b^3 }{c } +\frac{c^3 }{a} \geqslant \frac{1}{a+b+c} + \frac{(a+b+c)^3 }{a+b+c} $
$F(a+b+c)\ge 1+(a+b+c)^3$
$F\ge \frac{1}{a+b+c} + (a+b+c)^2$
That's it , what to do next ?

Now that you have come to $F\geq 1/z+z^2$ for some quantity $z$, you could try studying that function and find its minimum.

Actually, that function has a derivative of $2z-1/z^2$, which is $0$ when $z=\sqrt[3]{1/2}$. You can convince yourself however you like that it reaches a minimum over the positive reals at this point, and computing said minimum yields $\approx 1.68>1$. So you can in fact conclude to the desired inequality, with no equality cases.

Applying the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality:
$$(ab+bc+ca)\left(\frac{a^3}{b} +\frac{b^3 }{c} +\frac{c^3 }{a}   \right) \ge(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)^2 \ge (ab+bc+ca)(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)$$
$$\implies \frac{a^3}{b} +\frac{b^3 }{c} +\frac{c^3 }{a}\ge a^2 + b^2 + c^2 $$
Then applying the AM-GM inequality
$$F\ge \frac{1}{a^2 + b^2 + c^2} + (a^2 + b^2 + c^2) \ge 2\sqrt{\frac{1}{a^2 + b^2 + c^2} \cdot (a^2 + b^2 + c^2)} = 2>1$$
The equality cannot occur.

$ \large \frac{a^3 }{b} + \frac{b^3 }{c} + \frac{c^3 }{a} \overset{\text{Radon}}{\geqslant} (a+b+c)^2 $

$\frac{a^3 }{b} + \frac{b^3 }{c} + \frac{c^3 }{a} + \frac{1}{\underbrace{a^2 +b^2 +c^2 }_{\leqslant a+b+c } } \geqslant (a+b+c)^2 + \frac{1}{2(a+b+c)}  + \frac{1}{2(a+b+c)} \overset{\text{AM-GM}}{\geqslant} \frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{4}} \geqslant 1 $
